# Google script, copy row from a sheet to another with condition and date

Tags: google-sheets

In my google script, I try to copy some row, with a data condition from a sheet to another sheet

I have a problem with the date getting from a sheet

I tried the follow:

```
var date_check = new Date(data[i][4]);
```

where [i] is the index, and 4 the column where date is it.(log tell me just the relative number, so I tried to create new date from that number, but generates just a NaN variable.

this is all the code

```
function copy() {


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('ISCRITTI');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('2012');
 var todayDate = new Date('1/1/2012');
  var data = sheet1.getRange(2,1, sheet1.getLastRow(), sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var dest = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    Logger.log(data[i][4]);// return a number not the date in the sheets
    var date_check = new Date(data[i][4]);
    Logger.log(date_check); // return NaN
     Logger.log(todayDate.getFullYear()); //return 2012.0
    if ( todayDate.getFullYear()===date_check.getFullYear()) { 
     dest.push(data[i]); 
    }
  } // here is the end of the for loop



  if (dest.length > 0 ) { 
    sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,dest.length,dest[0].length).setValues(dest);
  }
}
```

What I missing? thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me.  I modified it to work in my environment and I took out all of the date checking stuff and used getDataRange.

```
function copy() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dest = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) 
  {
     dest.push(data[i]); 
  } 
  sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow()+1,1,dest.length,dest[0].length).setValues(dest);
}
```